# struct with evaluated/calculated attributes in Julia

Tags: julia

I am incredibly new to Julia, as in I downloaded it yesterday. I need to use structs for a project I am trying to start. I need my objects to consist of attributes that are part of the input and attributes that are calculated from that input. For example, I tried:

```
struct Bar
    #Attributes from input
    E::Float64
    A::Float64
    L::Float64

    # Attributes calculated form input
    k = (E*A/L)*[1.0 -1.0; -1.0 1.0]
end
```

but I get an error:

```
ERROR: LoadError: syntax: "k = (((E * A) / L) * [1 -1; -1 1])" inside type definition is reserved around Untitled-1:10
```

How should I go about achieving my desired outcome?

Comment: Hi, could you accept one of the answers so that this question doesn't show up as "Unanswered"? Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need any special package or macro to do this. Just do it the standard way, in the constructor. The last struct attribute isn't some sort of special 'evaluated attribute', it's a completely ordinary attribute.

```
 struct Bar
    E::Float64
    A::Float64
    L::Float64
    k::Matrix{Float64}
 end
 Bar(e, a, l) = Bar(e, a, l, (e*a/l)*[1 -1; -1 1])
 
 jl> Bar(2,3,4)
 Bar(2.0, 3.0, 4.0, [1.5 -1.5; -1.5 1.5])
```

Comment: To expand the answer of @DNF, the idea is that the logic for attributes that need to be computed (or value-checked) can be put in a custom struct constructor, i.e. a function with the same name as the struct and that returns an object of that type..

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
Base.@kwdef struct Bar                                                                                                    
    E::Float64                                                             
    A::Float64                                                             
    L::Float64                                                             
    k::Matrix{Float64} = (E*A/L) .* [1.0 -1.0; -1.0 1.0]                   
end
```

and now:

```
julia> Bar(;E=1,A=2,L=3)
Bar(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, [0.6666666666666666 -0.6666666666666666; -0.6666666666666666 0.6666666666666666])
```

Important notes:

- always define field type if possible - even when you set the default value for it
- instead of `Base.@kwdef` you could try `using Parameters` package and the `Parameters.@with_kw` macro which is more powerful and has more options.